# Integrating $ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} i \operatorname{arctanh} \left( \sin\theta+i\alpha \right) \, \mathrm{d}\theta $ when $\alpha\ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

While i am trying to solve a physical mathematical problem, one has to deal with the following integral as an intermediate step
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} i \operatorname{arctanh} \left( \sin\theta+i\alpha \right) \, \mathrm{d}\theta \, , 
$$
where $\alpha\ge 0$.

> Using Computer algebra systems (CAS) such as Maple, it can be noticed that the integral is really valued.

The integral can most likely be evaluated analytically by contour integration and using the residue theorem. However, i have no clue how to proceed.

Any thoughts or hints that can help a bit would be highly desirable.

Thank you

Volterra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be solved using contour integration, or just reduced to (already [used](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3264756) by myself) $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\ln(1-2r\cos\theta+r^2)~d\theta=0\qquad(r\in\mathbb{C},|r|<1)$$ where the principal value of the logarithm is taken; I think the easiest way to see it is from $$\ln(1-2r\cos\theta+r^2)=\ln(1-re^{i\theta})(1-re^{-i\theta})=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^n\cos n\theta}{n}.$$
This can be rewritten as $\int_{-\pi}^\pi\ln\left(\frac{1+r^2}{2r}-\cos\theta\right)~d\theta=-2\pi\ln r$; clearly (using substitution and periodicity), $\cos\theta$ can be replaced by $\pm\sin\theta$ here. Since $\operatorname{arctanh}(\sin\theta+i\alpha)=\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{1+\sin\theta+i\alpha}{1-\sin\theta-i\alpha}$, the answer is $$i\pi\big(\ln r(-\alpha)-\ln r(\alpha)\big)=2\pi\arg r(\alpha),$$ where $r=r(\alpha)$ is the solution of $1+r^2=2r(1+i\alpha)$ satisfying $|r|<1$ (for $\alpha>0$; the case $\alpha=0$ is covered by continuity, or just solved immediately). This may be evaluated in closed form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You mean the integral vanishes or what? i am afraid i cannot see that clearly

Comment: Yes, *my first integral* vanishes (but not yours). Each $\color{DarkBlue}{\cos}$ vanishes when integrated.

Comment: i see -- but how my integral can be reduced to yours? Can you elaborate a bit further please?

Comment: I've rewritten the relevant part of the answer.